# how to set a watch in the vim debugger

Tags: vimrc, plugin-system

I use [DBGp Remote Debugger Interface](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2508) for debuggign in vim. which works excellent, but it's missing some things that I would like to have:

- a watch variable features (most important)
- auto complete when evaluating an expression
- going through previous expression evaluation history

any recommendations on other vim debugging plugins that have these?

[image]

Comment: I guess this question is [off-topic](https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). In any case, you could use check the [options in Vim Awesome](https://vimawesome.com/?q=debugger) -- the first result in this link is about a multi-language debugger that supports PHP. In its description it mentions that it is a continuation of the plugin you referenced.

Comment: multi-language? i never asked about multi-language support

Comment: it seems you stopped reading at that word -- or actually only read that part

Comment: it seems that you are right  my bad

Comment: tried it.. works perfectly!

Comment: great, I'm glad to hear that